# Execute method after getting response from $http.get

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I want to add a profile if it doesn't exist, otherwise, I will only do an update:

```
profileExists(id) {
    return this.$http.get('/profiles/' + id).then(response => {
            return response.data;
        });
}

submitProfile(profile) {
    if (!this.profileExists(profile.id)) {
        this.addProfile(profile);
    } else {
        this.updateProfile(profile);
    }
}

addProfile(profile) {
    return this.$http.post('/profiles', profile)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(this.$http.fallback);
}

updateProfile(profile) {
    return this.$http.put('/profiles/' + profile.id)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(this.$http.fallback);
}
```

The problem with this code is that in the `submitProfile` method, `this.addProfile(profile);` is executed before the return statement of `profileExists(id)`... I have a hard time manipulating asynchronous code. I don't know how to execute the code after finishing all the `profileExists(id)` method.

And my second question is why do we put a return statement on `this.$http.get` or `this.$http.put`?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the profileExists throw an error in case profile id is not found. You can handle such scenario using subscribe method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think's you need to call your addProfile() in success callback from your profileExists()

Try this.

```
profileExists(id) {
    return this.$http.get('/profiles/' + id).then(response => {
            if(!response.data){
                 this.addProfile(profile);
            }else{
                 this.updateProfile(profile);
            }
        });
}
```

Or

```
profileExists(id){
     return this.$http.get('/profiles/' + id);
}

submitProfile(profile) {
this.profileExists(profile.id).then(response => {
     if (!response.data) {
          this.addProfile(profile);
     } else {
        this.updateProfile(profile);
     }
   })

}
```

Answer (score 2):

By the time your code reaches the `if` clause, `profileExists` has not returned, so it evaluates to `false`. You can change your code to check in the callback function

```
submitProfile(profile) {
    this.profileExists(profile.id)
       .then(response => {
           if(!response.data){
               this.addProfile(profile);
           } else {
               this.updateProfile(profile);
           }
       })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
submitProfile(profile) {
    return this.profileExists(profile.id)
       .then(exists => {
           if(!exists){
               return this.addProfile(profile);
           } else {
               return this.updateProfile(profile);
           }
    })
}
```

We put return before the actual call because we want to return the promise . So whomever is calling `submitProfile` can perform some action after this action is performed. Like this :

```
service.submitProfile(profile)
  .then(result => console.log('submit success'));
```

Also they can catch errors wherever it happened in all the code above in single place.

```
service.submitProfile(profile)
  .then(result => console.log('submit success'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Failed to submit',err);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set async http true. Try adding this line of code in your config.

```
$httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);
```